# 'NoneType' object has no attribute delete

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I have created a program that creates a citation based on entrybox inputs. I am trying to add a button that clears all the entryboxes when clicked; however, I find that the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute delete` occurs since none of my entry boxes are packed. When I do replace `.place()` with `.pack()`, I find that it works. Is there any way to make this function work with un-padded entry boxes (as I need these boxes in specific locations)?

**This is the sample of my code:**

```
from tkinter import *

#create window
win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x500")

#clear function
def clearBoxes():
    author1Input.delete(0,END)

#entry box
author1 = StringVar()
author1Input = Entry(win,textvariable=author1).place(x=30,y=120)

#button to clear
Button(win,text="Clear",command=clearBoxes).place(x=30,y=200)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: `nameInput` is `None`.  We can't say why that is, because you haven't shown us the code where that variable is assigned.

Comment: what is `nameInput`? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: typed the wrong variabled name, fixed "nameInput" to "author1Input".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Function `def clearBoxes():` needs parameter or else nameInput is not referencing anything. You should pass `Entry` object as parameter.
- For whatever reason, having `author1Input = Entry(win,textvariable=author1).place(x=30,y=120)` in one line messes this up. It needs to be placed after widget has been defined. Someone smarter than me can explain why.

Here is full solution.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

#create window
win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x500")

#clear function
def clearBoxes(nameInput):
    nameInput.delete(0,END)

#entry box
author1 = StringVar()
author1Input = Entry(win,textvariable=author1)
author1Input.place(x=30,y=120)

func = partial(clearBoxes, author1Input)

#button to clear
Button(win,text="Clear",command=func).place(x=30,y=200)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works. It's weird that adding commands onto the variable messed it up. I ended up calling the function directly and changing "nameInput" to "author1Input" to avoid the use for the partial function tool. Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly using ``command=function()`` will call function when ``Button`` is created, so it cannot have this: ``()``.